# Equation and system of equation on the same line - Adding numeration

Tags: equations, numbering

I need that LaTeX number the following element (equation + system of equation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x)=e^{\alpha x}P(x) +
\begin{sistema}
\cos(\beta x) \\
\sin(\beta x)
\end{sistema}
\]
\end{document}
```

The above element should have only one number as it was a normal equation. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, replace `\[ … \]` with `\begin{equation … \end{equation}`. B.t.w., why not simply use the `cases` environment; rather than defining a new one?

Comment: Hello @Bernard thank you very much for your hints

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Comment: @Bernard The `cases` environment would add unwanted horizontal space at its right. On the other hand, this particular case seems to be one where `cases` should be used, adding the condition whereby either branch should be chosen.

Comment: @egerg: I wondered whether the quad separating the columns would be added in case there's no second column.